# For what value of a and b will the given sequence and series converge, given that a, b > 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

### $S_n$ = $\frac{n^a+3}{n^b-1}$

I know that if we take $lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$, and get a value L then it converges. If we get something that is either undefined or tends to $\infty$, then the sequence does not converge.

The question asks us for the value of a and b (which has to be greater than 1) which can be applied to make the sequence convergent, but upon applying the limits, I am ending up with an indeterminate form. How should I proceed with this?

Comment: What happens if $n^a$ grows faster than $n^b$? What happens if $n^b$ grows faster than $n^a$? What happens if $n^a$ grows as fast as $n^b?$

Comment: @vitamind I see where you are going with that. I think I should be able to do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $a=b$. Then

$$S_n=\frac{1+ \frac{3}{n^a}}{1-\frac{1}{n^a}} \to 1.$$

Case 2: $a<b$. Then

$$S_n=\frac{n^{a-b}+ \frac{3}{n^b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}} .$$

Since $n^{a-b}= \frac{1}{n^{b-a}}$ and $b-a >0$, we get

$$S_n \to 0.$$

Case 3: $a>b$. This is your turn.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: The first case has limit 1, not 0. The second case you first write that it has limit 1 and then that it has limit 0.

Comment: Ooops ! I have made an edit.

Comment: @Fred so correct me if I'm wrong but since in the above two cases, we are indeed getting real values (L), this would imply that the above is indeed convergent for those two cases. Am I right in my understanding there?

Comment: yes, in the first two cases the sequence is convergent,  in the third case the sequence is divergent

Answer (score 0):

Case-$1$,

Now,, for $b\gt a $, $$\frac{1+\frac{3}{n^a}}{n^{b-a}-\frac{1}{n^a}} \to 0 $$ as $n \to \infty$

Case-$2$

for $b=a$ , $$\frac{1+\frac{3}{n^a}}{n^{b-a}-\frac{1}{n^a}} \to 1 $$ as $n \to \infty$

Case-$3$

For $a\gt b$ , $$\frac{n^{a-b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}} + \frac{\frac{3}{n^b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}}$$

We show divergence using the first part $$\frac{n^{a-b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}}$$,  ( since, $$\frac{\frac{3}{n^b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}} \to 0 $$ as $n \to \infty $)

As, $$\frac{n^{a-b}}{1-\frac{1}{n^b}} \gt n^{a-b}$$

Now, however large $G$ , we take , we always find $n=\lceil (G+1)^{\frac{1}{a-b}} \rceil $ such that $n^{a-b} \gt G $

Proving the sequence is divergent for $a \gt b $

Hence , the result.